# Plotting an inverse regression curve using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two regression lines onto the same scatter plot. It looks like I have it almost right using ggplot. I have one fit, using a second order term and another fit where the inverse of hours is the dependent variable and the inverse of cases is the predictor. The data is as follows:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'hours cases
   1275 230
  1350 235
  1650 250
  2000 277
  3750 522
  4222 545
  5018 625
  6125 713
  6200 735
  8150 820
  9975 992
  12200 1322
  12750 1900
  13014 2022
  13275 2155
  '), header = TRUE)
```

I have the following, but it looks like the inverse regression fit is out of whack. What adjustment could be made to get the correct curve? I know the curve should be concave up and increasing.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = cases, y = hours)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=3.2,fill="green",color="black")+
  geom_smooth(span=.4,method="lm",formula=y~x+I(x^2))+
  geom_smooth(span=.4,method="lm",formula=I(1/y)~I(1/x))
```

[image]

For reference, just a scatter plot of the predicted value of y against x, where note, the y axis is the inverse of the predicted value of 1/y, we get

[image]

The code used to produce this was

```
fit<-lm(I(1/hours)~I(1/cases),data=df)
summary(fit)

hw <- theme(
  plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5,face='bold'),
  axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0,vjust=.5,face='bold'),
  axis.title.x=element_text(face='bold'),
  plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5),
  plot.caption=element_text(hjust=-.5),
  strip.text.y = element_blank(),
  strip.background=element_rect(fill=rgb(.9,.95,1),
                                colour=gray(.5), size=.2),
  panel.border=element_rect(fill=FALSE,colour=gray(.70)),
  panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
  panel.spacing.x = unit(0.10,"cm"),
  panel.spacing.y = unit(0.05,"cm"),

  axis.ticks=element_blank(),
  axis.text=element_text(colour="black"),
  axis.text.y=element_text(margin=margin(0,3,0,3)),
  axis.text.x=element_text(margin=margin(-1,0,3,0)),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray")
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=cases,y=1/fitted(fit))) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=3.2,fill="green",color="black")+
  labs(x="Surgical Cases",
       y="Predicted Worker Hours",
       title="Predicted Worker Hours vs Surgical Cases")+hw
```

Comment: That looks like a perfect fit to me - in what way is it out of wack? I'm not sure what you mean by "I know the curve should be concave up and increasing."

Comment: Referring to the line that looks like the function y=0, I think it is plotting 1/y on the y axis, when I want it to convert to the predicted y

Comment: What was the code for the second plot?

Comment: I have included that in my original post.

Comment: You'll have to fit the second regression model outside of ggplot2. `geom_smooth` can't transform the predicted values.

Comment: How could I do it using a different method such as the plot and lines functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. Including the confidence interval would require additional work (e.g., calculate values for the confidence band outside of ggplot2). I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```
fit2 <- lm(I(1/hours)~I(1/cases), data = df)

ggplot(df, aes(x = cases, y = hours)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=3.2,fill="green",color="black")+
  geom_smooth(span=.4,method="lm",formula=y~x+I(x^2), aes(color = "polyn"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 1 / predict(fit2, newdata = data.frame(cases = x)), 
                aes(color = "inv-inv"), size = 1)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland said, you need to plot the actual model.

But, the problem is that geom_smooth has a formula argument that doesn't like formulas. So, even though the formula below is correct, it doesn't plot the right line.

Using summary(fit) to get a (-0.00005507) and b (0.1743), the intercept and slope of the line:

```
  geom_smooth(span=.4,method="lm", formula=y~I(1/((1/x)*0.1743-0.00005507)))
```